# React: ES2020 dynamic import in useEffect blocks rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, code-splitting, dynamic-import

From what I understand, async code inside `useEffect` runs without blocking the rendering process. So if I have a component like this:

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const log = () => console.log("window loaded");
    window.addEventListener("load", log);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("load", log);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      console.log("begin");
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log("end");
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return null;
};
```

The console output is (in order):

> ```
> begin
> window loaded
> end
> ```

However if I use ES2020 dynamic import inside the useEffect:

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const log = () => console.log("window loaded");
    window.addEventListener("load", log);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("load", log);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      console.log("begin");
      const data = await import("./data.json");
      console.log("end");
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return null;
};
```

The output is (in order):

> ```
> begin
> end
> window loaded
> ```

This is a problem because when `data.json` is very large, the browser hangs while importing the large file before React renders anything.

Comment: Anything that runs in the UI thread will block rendering if the operations are extremely heavy (such as loading your data). You should offload that loading to a web worker instead, so that it doesn’t block the UI thread.

Comment: @Terry but shouldn't the browser finish loading first and then the UI freezes while importing the data?

Comment: The window `load` event fires quite late into the lifecycle of a page, because it waits for all resources/assets to be loaded. In your case, the `fetch()` operation has already returned a response (but your UI thread locks up when receiving and processing the response) before the window load event is fired.

Comment: @Terry oh ok, thanks for the info. Ideally I would like to import the data after window has loaded for SEO reasons. I don't mind the page freezing a little bit.

Comment: Then shouldn't you do that in the `load` event listener callback?

Comment: @Terry In my case the file i'm trying to dynamically import is actually a function that requires a large dataset. And I want to run this function whenever some state has changed so that's why I put it in a useEffect hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the necessary and useful information is in Terry's comments. here is the implementation of what you want according to the comments:

First goal:

> I would like to import the data after window has loaded for SEO reasons.

Second goal:

> In my case the file I'm trying to dynamically import is actually a function that requires a large dataset. And I want to run this function whenever some state has changed so that's why I put it in a useEffect hook.

##### Let's do it

You can create a function to get the data as you created it as `getData` with `useCallback` hook to use it anywhere without issue.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const result = await import('./data.json');
      setData(result);
    } catch (error) {
      // do a proper action for failure case
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      getData().then(() => console.log('data loaded successfully'));
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('load', () => {
        console.log('page unmounted');
      });
    };
  }, [getData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter) {
      getData().then(() => console.log('re load data after the counter state get change'));
    }
  }, [getData, counter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter((prevState) => prevState + 1)}>Increase Counter</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

##### Explanation:

With component did mount, the event listener will load the `data.json` on 'load' event. So far, the first goal has been met.

I use a sample and simple counter to demonstrate change in the state and reload `data.json` scenario. Now, with every change on `counter` value, the `getData` function will call because the second `useEffect` has the counter in its array of dependencies. Now the second goal has been met.

**Note:** The `if` block in the second `useEffect` prevent the `getData` calling after the component did mount and first invoking of `useEffect`

**Note:** Don't forget to use the catch block for failure cases.

**Note:** I set the result of `getData` to the `data` state, you might do a different approach for this result, but the other logics are the same.